# How to know what version of node I need to run a react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, version

I have a react app, the `npm install` and `npm start` operations to run it on `node v12.18.2` work perfectly but gives error on `node v17.3.0`. So how to know what versions of node can i use for the app to run successfully.

Answer (score 8):

The React application has a `package.json` file and in this file, it is usually specified the version of node it needs to run successfully. This information can be found in the section called engines

```
  {
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.3 <15"
    }
  }
```

The above code says that the application runs successfully if the version of node is higher than 0.10.3 but lower than 15.

Comment: No, that section isn't present in my package.json file, I do find it in the package-lock.json file but on a per package basis and just a few have it.

Comment: Another solution I might give you is to check the dependencies, devDependencies, and their versions. Some of the dependencies might work only with a specific version of node. In any case, it's a good practice to specify the engine information in the application you develop.

Comment: Thank's, I myself created the app and all i know is the specific version of node not a range like you show.